# prove that $|\hat{f}(t)| < \hat{f}(0)$ for all nonzero t

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral

> Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ (i.e. $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{C}, \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f| < \infty,$ where the integral is a Lebesgue integral, and $f$ is measurable), and assume $f$ is not zero almost everywhere and $f(x)\ge 0$ for almost every $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $|\hat{f}(t) | <\hat{f}(0)$ for all $t\neq 0$, where $\hat{f}(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(t)e^{-itx} dt$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

I know that for all $t\neq 0, |\hat{f}(t)| \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(t)|dt = \hat{f}(0),$ as $f(x)\ge 0$ almost everywhere. But I'm not sure how to make this inequality strict. I know that one can always choose $\alpha \in\mathbb{C}, |\alpha| = 1,$ so that $|\int g | = \int \alpha |g|$ for any $g\in L^1(\mathbb{R}).$

> Edit: one can use the fact to show that $\alpha f(t) e^{-itx} = f(t)$, so $\alpha = e^{itx}$ for all t with $f(t)$ nonzero. We may assume $m(\{f > 0\}) > 0$ as otherwise $f = 0$ almost everywhere, a contradiction. Hence $\{f > 0\}$ must be uncountable, and since for all $t$ in this set, $\alpha = e^{itx}, x$ is zero ($t$ must take on infinitely many distinct residues modulo $2\pi$ so $e^{itx}$ takes on infinitely many distinct values).

Comment: In your last sentence you need $|\alpha|\le1$ instead of $|\alpha|=1$.

Comment: As for the main statement, it's false as written since one can take $f(x)=0$ identically.

Comment: @GregMartin assume $f$ is not almost zero everywhere. Then I believe the statement should hold.

Comment: see also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1826266/supremum-of-absolute-value-of-the-fourier-transform-equals-1-and-it-is-attain?noredirect=1)